# Voting on Community Wiki feature

Tags: feature-request

**Voting on Community Wiki**

When viewing the question [What IDE to use for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python) I noticed that some answers were referring to the same product. To me this can be misleading because [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python/81603#81603) is rated 40 which is the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python/81608#81608) which is rated 14. When the votes are added the product, Active States's Komodo in this case, might be considered a better product than something with a higher rating. However it is my opinion without knowing the unique votes there is really no way to know which is a better product. What I think would be an appropriate solution would be for administrators to be able to merge the answers, the merged answer would retain the original authors, the administrator who merged it, and the unique votes.

Comment: Didn't you read the notice at the top?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean here, but note that poll-style questions, especially "Product X vs. Product Y" or "What is the best Z?" are generally not accepted anymore, and would get closed down quickly. Some old questions like the one you linked to do remain, however, but I don't think we should use them as a reason for adding new functionality.

Comment: @Rosinante Yes I read it, but how is that relevant to what I am suggesting?

Comment: @hammar I see, again thank you for that piece of insight. You seem to tell me why my idea is bad, thank you.

Comment: just as @hammar said. We don't do this any more.

Comment: Yet another reason why we shouldn't even keep around old questions like this, much less allow new ones. If this bothers you, feel free to flag that one for deletion.

Answer (score 4):

These questions are only around for historical reasons. Many of them have already been sent to Valhalla and the others might follow one day. As many have alrady pointed out in the comments, such questions are highly discouraged and off-topic and new ones normally vanish into oblivion.

As to your suggestion to merge answers, no, that does not serve any purpose. The system/community is self-regulating. Duplicate answers are welcome as long as they are not Copy&Paste and add something new to the solution or are differently stated.